# Amazon ECS tasks and autoscaling groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm relatively new to Amazon ECS and I have a question that bothers me.

In a process of testing a minimum-viable cluster I ran into realization that one couldn't create dynamically-sized service. There is only one choice specifying desired number of tasks changing service's parameter through console or CLI or CloudFormation. To put it differently, the number of tasks is *statically* defined. And that contradicts with autoscaling group's nature because it scales dynamically upon need.

So, how does one dynamically scale ECS tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I keep getting + points on this, my comment is no longer true. As Lukas said, there is new functionality and documentation and it *is* possible now. I'm leaving the following for historical reasons. AWS is always changing so please be weary about how old the information is when you decide your architectural decisions!

With auto-scaling groups you natively get to tie together auto-scale triggers with cloudwatch directly which is what you're hinting at when you say dynamically because you set a minimum, maximum and a +/- instance addition on cloudwatch alarms.

With ECS you can, it's just a bit different. There's a good post about it on the [amazon blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scaling-amazon-ecs-services-automatically-using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-aws-lambda/), but the gist of it is that you subscribe SNS topics to the Cloudwatch alarms, which trigger Lambda functions that increase or decrease the number of tasks. It's essentially the exact same functionality but you have more pieces to tie together. You could (and probably should) also have that alarm trigger your auto-scaling group for your ECS cluster as well.

[image]

Comment: Amazon introduced auto-scaling for ECS in May 2016. Please read the updated documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html